# Изменение размера Rect

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Как реализовать изменение размера прямоугольника или квадрата пропорционально?
Допустим потянув за поинтер который находится на нижнем левом угле.
Имеются координаты поинтера X|Y
Координаты мыши на полотне X|Y
Координаты offset поинтера X = stageX  - pointer.x | Y = stageY - pointer.y
Размеры прямоугольника или квадрата

```
    P4.on("mousedown", (e)=>
    {
        e.target.offset = {x: e.stageX - e.target.x, y: e.stageY - e.target.y}
    });
    
    P4.on("pressmove", (e)=>
    {
        var x = e.stageX - e.target.offset.x;
        var y = e.stageY - e.target.offset.y;

        e.target.x = x;
        e.target.y = y;
    });
```

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ширина была w, высота h, а мышь находится на расстоянии dx, dy от базового угла, то

```
if (w * dy > h * dx) {
   new_w = dx;
   new_h = dx * h / w;
}
else {
   new_h = dy;
   new_w = dy * w / h;
}
```

знак больше или меньше в ифе скорректируйте по желаемому поведению